# Limit to 10 in bar graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-visualization, bar-chart, altair

I am trying to do a bar graph using altair package in python. I have used the below code and got the output as below

```
alt.Chart(final1,title="Avg salary for IT Project Manager I in each company ").mark_bar(size=20).encode(
    alt.X("company:N", sort="-y"),
    alt.Y("average(salary)"),
    color=alt.condition(
        alt.datum.company == 'Celerity',  
        alt.value('orange'),     
        alt.value('steelblue')   
    )
).properties(width=800)
```

[image: Output Bar Graph]

Could any one help me in limiting it to only top 10 companies as the graph looks odd as i took all the companies. I tries to find a solution online but couldn't find any. Thanks in advance

Comment: What about sorting and then filtering input data? (e.g., `data[:10]`)

Comment: Alternatively, see this: https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/top_k_items.html

Comment: Thank you @floatingpurr made few changes to the code provided in the link and it worked.

Comment: @rishi Could you add your solution as an answer to the question so that it is marked as resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used added this property in the end and it worked for me. Thank you all for the help

```
.transform_window(
    rank='rank(salary)',
    sort=[alt.SortField('salary', order='descending')]
).transform_filter(
    (alt.datum.rank < 30)
).properties(width=400, height=300)
```